# Does del change the position of other items in the list?

Tags: python

If I use [the `del` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) in Python, will the positions of other items in the list change? For example, if you wrote `del list[0]`, would `list[1]` then move down and take the place of `list[0]`, or will it remain as `list[1]`?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the positions will change.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
del a[1]
print(a)  # -> [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. You should try it and see what happens!

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit confused, because my code is showing an error which I cannot explain otherwise. Time to go debugging!